# Float return value, indicate an error

Tags: c

My function returns a float value from an object. If the function cannot find a proper float value an error should be returned so i can deal with it properly in the code.

My question is how to return an error.

The option of adding an extra parameter and using it to set an error marker is not preferred.

I could return a magic value, is that a valid option? My float values in the program never exceed very large numbers ( never over 10^12) so returning an FLT_MAX to check an error might be an option.

Is there a better ( portable ) way?

Comment: Would returning `NaN` work?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That was my idea too, but forgetting to check for Nan will crash the program when the value is used(right?), settign it to an existing but large value, will keep it running even if the numbers are incorrect.

Comment: @this. `NaN`s are designed to silently propagate. Most functions will return `NaN` when passed a `NaN`, and comparisons using `NaN` return false

Comment: @JanDvorak exactly, i do not want that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning a magic value is the *only* option, except for setting a global (which is even worse).

The best solution *would* be to modify the prototype, to something like:

```
bool findAFloat(float *result);
```

That is clear, easy to use, and rather obvious.

You could also go for:

```
float findAFloat(float ifNotFound);
```

and have the caller decide what to return if no value is found.

Comment: +1 That's the preferred way to do it in C. The first API is also structured in a way that makes it hard to "forget" to check the value for error, which is a lot more likely when an API uses "magic numbers".

Comment: Cleanest solution. Just change the `bool` to something else since it's just for C and not C++ (C doesn't have a typedef for bool, has it?)

Comment: @Dirk It does have a `bool` (C99 IIRC), defined in `stdbool.h`

Comment: I had a second though about this;  `bool findAFloat(float *result);` is more correct.

Answer (score 7):

If you `#include <math.h>`, you can return `NAN` in case of error. This is the only float `f` for which `f == f` is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

(Edit - removed exception suggestion - didn't see this was 'c')

Apart from that, floating point numbers in c/c++ have special values - `infinite` and `NaN`

You could return a [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) if you want to signify 'no result'

Answer (score 2):

You could always set a static const int ERROR_VAL = max float. Then do something like `if(result == ERROR_VAL)...`

Answer (score 2):

I think returning `NAN` is an option, this shows how `NAN` and `isnan` work:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = NAN ;
    float b = 10 ;

    if( isnan( a ))
    {
      printf( "isnan\n") ;
    }

    if( isnan( b ))
    {
       printf( "isnan\n") ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set `errno` to, say, `ERANGE` and place the burden on the caller to set `errno = 0;` before the call and check it after returning from your function. That's similar to what some standard library functions do.

Answer (score 0):

There's one more way to deal with it. You can make a separate function to check that there is a proper value, and call the float returning one only if the check is passed.